# Right alignment inside a p:column holding a p:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Given the following `<p:panelGrid>`.

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 25%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="text-align: right;">
            a
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

The text inside `<p:column>` is aligned right as can be seen below.

[image]

I need to display another `<p:panelGrid>` inside that `<p:column>` as follows.

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 25%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="text-align: right;">
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        b
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

The style attribute `text-align: right;` of `<p:column>` has no effect in this case.

[image]

How to align the inner `<p:panelGrid>` right?

Comment: Have you tried style="margin-right:0%"

Comment: I had to use `float: right` anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `panelGrid` is a table you can float it to the right:

```
 <p:panelGrid style="width: 25%;">
    <p:row>
       <p:column>
           <p:panelGrid style="float: right">
               <p:row>
                   <p:column>
                       b
                   </p:column>
               </p:row>
           </p:panelGrid>
       </p:column>
   </p:row>
 </p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the style on the inner panelgrid

```
<p:panelGrid style="text-align: right; display:inline-block">
```

Comment: Adding this style attribute `display:inline-block` does not function.

Answer (score 1):

Add class for the panel and apply the styles like below.

```
 <p:panelGrid style="width: 25%;" styleClass="mytest">
 <p:row>
    <p:column>
        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    b
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:column>
 </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

**CSS**

```
.mytest td
{
  text-align:right;
}
```

If not work then try the below.

```
.mytest td
{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: The outer `<p:panelGrid>` actually contains many rows/columns than shown in the question. Applying this CSS to the outer `<p:panelGrid>` would align them all right which is undesired. Not all rows/columns should be aligned right. The right alignment should apply only to the inner `<p:panelGrid>`. Moreover, `float : right` is undesired in this case which changes the appearance of `<p:panelGrid>`.